# Part of submenu shown outside of page

Tags: css

I have a horizontal navigation menu and some menus have submenu, when I hover to a menu that is close to the right side of page, it not show the full submenu list, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fdjsf/) is the fiddle file. Any advice? View [full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/fdjsf/embedded/result/) and hover on `Short Movies` for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some css and HTML changes.

Check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Shinov/fdjsf/8/embedded/result/

```
.dropdown_1column {
  width: 140px;
}
.dropdown_2columns {
  width: 280px;
}
...
```

Comment: Your change had bad effect on Movies, Series, Shows menus

Answer (score 0):

xoemab, I think it is your screen size that doesn't show the full sub menu I think. Here is a screenshot of my screen, I believe it shows the whole sub menu. !Hope this helps...I think reducing the width of your sub menus and placing them vertically might help?   ( Never mind I cannot post a screen shot... I am too new here! ) If you share your email I can send the screen shot to you... :-)

Comment: where is the screen? Upload to tinypic.com

Comment: Xeomab... here is the pic uploaded to tinypic.com http://i39.tinypic.com/2wfsmlx.jpg

Comment: Xoemab ... your #navbar {width:auto;} causes the problem I think. After trying a fixed width it looks good!

Comment: it must remain auto, your screen is just wider than mine thats why you dont have this problem :/ It would be great when there is no space at right make the submenus on the left.